# Stored procedure, grouping output into a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure below, it allows me to select a question id and list the username and their answer.

How would i change it so it only shows me the question id with a **new column called total** as below

[image]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.report
  @Question_ID varchar(5)
AS
  SELECT * FROM submit_Answer
  WHERE Question_ID=@Question_ID
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get one row for each Question_ID and Answer and count the number of occurrences in column Total.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.report
  @Question_ID varchar(5)
AS
  SELECT Question_ID,
         Answer,
         COUNT(*) as Total
  FROM submit_Answer
  WHERE Question_ID=@Question_ID
  GROUP BY Question_ID,
           Answer
```